# Clearing the uninstalled app's unmet dependencies

Tags: apt

First off, I'm new to Linux.
Now, I've tried installing a music player called Clementine (on Kali Linux 2.0 x64) but it hasn't been (properly?) installed (since I can see it's icon in the app list). Now everytime I try to update/upgrade the source lists, I get the following errors in accordance to the improper install of Clementine:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 clementine : Depends: libgpod4 (>= 0.6.0) but it is not installed
              Depends: liblastfm1 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqca2 (>= 2.0.2) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqjson0 (>= 0.7.1) but it is not installed
              Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly but it is not installable
              Depends: libprojectm-data but it is not installable or
                       projectm-data but it is not installed
 libqca2-plugin-ossl : Depends: libqca2 (>= 2.0.2) but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Please, please help me out here!

Comment: Seems you're using `apt-get`, please try `aptitude` and see if that helps. Syntax for simple stuff is mostly the same.

Comment: Do you want to make Clementine work, or remove it completely?

Comment: I would love to make it work. But then, if that isn't possible, then I might as well remove it.

Comment: Can you show us your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file?

Comment: deb http://http.kali.org/kali main contrib non-free

deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free

deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali-rolling/updates main contrib non-free

Comment: Sorry for the cluttered comment. I don't know why did the post just delete all the empty lines from the preview.

Comment: It would be better if you edit your post and include `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
```

From the [apt-get man page](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=apt-get&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8+jessie&format=html&locale=en):

> -f, --fix-broken
>
> Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This option, when used with install/remove, can
>              omit any packages to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. If packages are specified, these have to completely
>              correct the problem. The option is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT itself does not allow
>              broken package dependencies to exist on a system. It is possible that a system's dependency structure can be so corrupt
>              as to require manual intervention (which usually means using dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the offending
>              packages). Use of this option together with -m may produce an error in some situations. Configuration Item:
>              APT::Get::Fix-Broken.

Comment: Does no good. It gives me the exact same result that I have posted in the original post.

Comment: So you have to edit your question and post the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the content of all files under the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.

Comment: and also try the following three commands: `sudo apt-get purge clementine`, `sudo apt-get autoremove`, `sudo apt-get install clementine`

Comment: 'sudo apt-get purge clementine' does clear out the unmet dependencies for Clementine, but only for that particular instance. So, when I type 'apt-get install' again, the same unmet dependencies show up. So, is there a way that I can permanently "purge" Clementine out of my system?

Comment: What do you mean by "that particular instance"? Is there other instances?